# Why changing text in properties file (using ConstantsWithLookup) doesn't make any change in the constants in Production Mode?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

Here is my problem. I want to change the Constants dynamically for my web app when it's already in the Production Mode.

So here is what I did

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.ConstantsWithLookup;
public interface MyConstants extends ConstantsWithLookup{
   String email();
}
```

In the MyConstants.properties file

```
email=My email
```

Now i compiled the whole project & deploy it into server. At first test in server, it showed correctly "My email", then I went to `C:\tomcat\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\classes\myApp\client\MyConstants.properties` & change the text in that file to:

```
email=Your email
```

Now i ran myApp in tomcat but nothing happened. It still uses the `My email` String rather than `Your email` string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java class PropertiesConfiguration in the Apache Common Configuration library. This class allow to bind a properties file to an PropertiesConfiguration Java Object through which read the single properties.

[hot-reload-of-properties-file](http://www.madbit.org/blog/programming/30/hot-reload-of-properties-file/).

Steps to follow:

- Write code at server side that is mentioned in above link.
- At page load in `onModuleLoad()` make a GWT RPC call to read it from server based on user Locale and save it some where at client side.

Properties files must be outside of the war/jar file.